# Method 2D-Array display numbers

Tags: c#, arrays, methods, multidimensional-array

Hi, I have a problem. My code is supposed to display random numbers and add together all the odd numbers but my problem is that it only generates  a bunch of 0's. If anyone is willing to help me, I be very thankful.

I wrote many similar codes but this is the only one that only generates 0 and I have no clue what is wrong with it.

```
    int[,] A = new int[5, 7];
    Random rand = new Random();

    private void SumOdd(int[,] array)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        int rows = array.GetLength(0);
        int cols = array.GetLength(1);

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                if (sum % 2 != 0)
                {
                    array[i, j] = rand.Next(-100, 100);
                    sum += array[i, j];
                }
                richTextBox1.AppendText(array[i, j] + " ");
            }
        }
        richTextBox1.AppendText("The Sum of all Odd is: "+ sum.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Put a breakpoint at your `if` statement and you will know what is wrong.

Comment: @DatVM It tells me array[i,j] = rand.Next(-100, 100); something is wrong with it but where do i place it then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see one "odd" thing: First you initialize `sum` with `0`. So far so good. Then you test it if it is odd with `sum % 2 != 0`. Since `sum` is zero, that criterium will never be true, so it will never come inside that scope which will change the sum.

I think you want to test the new random number for oddnes, so try this:

```
int[,] A = new int[5, 7];
Random rand = new Random();

private void SumOdd(int[,] array)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int rows = array.GetLength(0);
    int cols = array.GetLength(1);

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            int value = rand.Next(-100, 100); // Create a new random number.
            array[i, j] = value;  // Store it in the array.
            richTextBox1.AppendText(value + " "); // Display it in the textbox.
            if (value % 2 != 0) // Test if it is odd.
                sum += value; // If so... add it to the sum.
        }
    }
    richTextBox1.AppendText("The Sum of all Odd is: "+ sum.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sum = 0;

if (sum % 2 != 0) 
{
  // never reaches here
  // sum % 2 is always 0 in your case
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (sum % 2 != 0)
```

When the code reaches this point, sum is initially 0. So, when computed, 0 / 2 remains 0. The block in the if will only execute if the remainder is NOT 0.

Put

```
array[i, j] = rand.Next(-100, 100);
```

outside of the if, if you want the number to be randomized before sum changes value.

Also, you say you want to add the odd numbers; well, this checks the sum, not the randomly generated number. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

i build it using console application and it works great

```
 static Random rand; 
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                int[,] A = new int[5, 7];
              rand = new Random();

              SumOdd(ref A);                 


                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            private static void SumOdd(ref int[,] array)
            {
                int sum = 0;
                int rows = array.GetLength(0);
                int cols = array.GetLength(1);

                for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                    {
                        array[i, j] = rand.Next(-100, 100);
                        if (array[i,j] % 2 != 0)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(array[i, j]);
                            sum += array[i, j];
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine(array[i, j] + " ");
                    }
                }
               Console.WriteLine("The Sum of all Odd is: " + sum.ToString());
            }
```